# cannot access array in heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

Why is this code giving an error on the line where I try to access `$sector_value['sector_info']['purchase_order'];`? But not in the fifth line where I print out the variable `$sector_counter`?

```
//SECTOR
$email_body .=  <<<SECTOR_DETAILS
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Sector $sector_counter;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Purchase order
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        $sector_value['sector_info']['purchase_order'];
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Proof
        </td>
    </tr>

SECTOR_DETAILS;
```

This is the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/www2isco/public_html/test/bch/queries/submit_order.php on line 44

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Enclose the variable in `{ .. }`, it's in [the docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
//SECTOR
$email_body .=  <<<SECTOR_DETAILS
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Sector $sector_counter;
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Purchase order
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
        {$sector_value['sector_info']['purchase_order']}
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            Proof
        </td>
    </tr>

SECTOR_DETAILS;
```